# How to create site on WSGI without frameworks

Tags: python, wsgi

I want to write site engine, but without any frameworks, only python standart library and some side modules like redis-py. But i don't know where should i start from and how should i do it.

I searched in google articles on this theme, but found nothing.

Can you give me link on where this theme is describe completely?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find complete solution, but you can start from [this tutorial](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/do-it-yourself.html), and [this one](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2007/5/21/getting-started-with-wsgi/).

Then add 'model' stuff like redis-py.